# Use of spread to add new attribute ads unexpected output

Tags: javascript

I'm using this to assign a new attribute to an object.

```
reportsMinusComments.map(v => {
            return {...v, comment: v.comment.map(c => {
                let newValue = sumFunc(c.like, 'value');
                return c['likeTotalForComment'] = { ...c, likeTotalForComment: newValue}
            })}
            }
        );
```

The attribute is being assigned as expected.

However, the unexpected consequence is that there is a ton of unexpected code being added to the output. How do I get rid of this?

```
[
      {
                "$__": {
                    "strictMode": true,
                    "selected": {},
                    "getters": {},
                    "_id": "5d9cb47eb6678675db488729",
                    "populated": {
                        "reply": {
                            "value": [],
                            "options": {
                                "_docs": {
                                    "5d9cb47eb6678675db488729": [],
                                    "5d9cb485b6678675db48872a": []
                                },
                                "path": "reply",
                                "populate": [
                                    {
                                        "_docs": {},
                                        "path": "like"
                                    },
                                    {
                                        "_docs": {},
                                        "path": "reply",
                                        "populate": [
                                            {
                                                "_docs": {},
                                                "path": "like"
                                            }
                                        ]
                                    },
                                    {
                                        "_docs": {},
                                        "path": "reply",
                                        "populate": [
                                            {
                                                "_docs": {},
                                                "path": "reply",
                                                "populate": [
                                                    {
                                                        "_docs": {},
                                                        "path": "like"
                                                    }
                                                ]
                                            }
                                        ]
                                    },
                                    {
                                        "_docs": {},
                                        "path": "reply",
                                        "populate": [
                                            {
                                                "_docs": {},
                                                "path": "reply",
                                                "populate": [
                                                    {
                                                        "_docs": {},
                                                        "path": "reply",
                                                        "populate": [
                                                            {
                                                                "_docs": {},
                                                                "path": "like"
                                                            }
                                                        ]
                                                    }
                                                ]
                                            }
                                        ]
                                    }
                                ],
                                "_queryProjection": {},
                                "isVirtual": false,
                                "virtual": null
                            }
                        },
                        "like": {
                            "value": [],
                            "options": {
                                "_docs": {
                                    "5d9cb47eb6678675db488729": [],
                                    "5d9cb485b6678675db48872a": [
                                        "5d9cb491b6678675db48872b"
                                    ]
                                },
                                "path": "like",
                                "_queryProjection": {},
                                "isVirtual": false,
                                "virtual": null
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    "wasPopulated": true,
                    "activePaths": {
                        "paths": {
                            "like": "init",
                            "reply": "init",
                            "_id": "init",
                            "content": "init",
                            "user_id": "init",
                            "user_name": "init",
                            "parent_comment_id": "init",
                            "_report": "init",
                            "createdAt": "init",
                            "updatedAt": "init",
                            "__v": "init"
                        },
                        "states": {
                            "ignore": {},
                            "default": {},
                            "init": {
                                "_id": true,
                                "like": true,
                                "reply": true,
                                "content": true,
                                "user_id": true,
                                "user_name": true,
                                "parent_comment_id": true,
                                "_report": true,
                                "createdAt": true,
                                "updatedAt": true,
                                "__v": true
                            },
                            "modify": {},
                            "require": {}
                        },
                        "stateNames": [
                            "require",
                            "modify",
                            "init",
                            "default",
                            "ignore"
                        ]
                    },
                    "pathsToScopes": {},
                    "cachedRequired": {},
                    "session": null,
                    "$setCalled": {},
                    "emitter": {
                        "_events": {},
                        "_eventsCount": 0,
                        "_maxListeners": 0
                    },
                    "$options": {
                        "skipId": true,
                        "isNew": false,
                        "willInit": true
                    }
                },
                "isNew": false,
                "_doc": {
                    "like": [],
                    "reply": [],
                    "_id": "5d9cb47eb6678675db488729",
                    "content": "1",
                    "user_id": "830052d6-e85d-450e-a1bf-b4157d122d9a",
                    "user_name": "ronmexico",
                    "parent_comment_id": null,
                    "_report": "5d7e5dfcbf409e0f543a8cd7",
                    "createdAt": "2019-10-08T16:08:30.803Z",
                    "updatedAt": "2019-10-08T16:08:30.803Z",
                    "__v": 0
                },
                "$locals": {},
                "$init": true,
                "likeTotalForComment": 0
            },
            {
                "$__": {
                    "strictMode": true,
                    "selected": {},
                    "getters": {},
                    "_id": "5d9cb485b6678675db48872a",
                    "populated": {
                        "reply": {
                            "value": [],
                            "options": {
                                "_docs": {
                                    "5d9cb47eb6678675db488729": [],
                                    "5d9cb485b6678675db48872a": []
                                },
                                "path": "reply",
                                "populate": [
                                    {
                                        "_docs": {},
                                        "path": "like"
                                    },
                                    {
                                        "_docs": {},
                                        "path": "reply",
                                        "populate": [
                                            {
                                                "_docs": {},
                                                "path": "like"
                                            }
                                        ]
                                    },
                                    {
                                        "_docs": {},
                                        "path": "reply",
                                        "populate": [
                                            {
                                                "_docs": {},
                                                "path": "reply",
                                                "populate": [
                                                    {
                                                        "_docs": {},
                                                        "path": "like"
                                                    }
                                                ]
                                            }
                                        ]
                                    },
                                    {
                                        "_docs": {},
                                        "path": "reply",
                                        "populate": [
                                            {
                                                "_docs": {},
                                                "path": "reply",
                                                "populate": [
                                                    {
                                                        "_docs": {},
                                                        "path": "reply",
                                                        "populate": [
                                                            {
                                                                "_docs": {},
                                                                "path": "like"
                                                            }
                                                        ]
                                                    }
                                                ]
                                            }
                                        ]
                                    }
                                ],
                                "_queryProjection": {},
                                "isVirtual": false,
                                "virtual": null
                            }
                        },
                        "like": {
                            "value": [
                                "5d9cb491b6678675db48872b"
                            ],
                            "options": {
                                "_docs": {
                                    "5d9cb47eb6678675db488729": [],
                                    "5d9cb485b6678675db48872a": [
                                        "5d9cb491b6678675db48872b"
                                    ]
                                },
                                "path": "like",
                                "_queryProjection": {},
                                "isVirtual": false,
                                "virtual": null
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    "wasPopulated": true,
                    "activePaths": {
                        "paths": {
                            "like": "init",
                            "reply": "init",
                            "_id": "init",
                            "content": "init",
                            "user_id": "init",
                            "user_name": "init",
                            "parent_comment_id": "init",
                            "_report": "init",
                            "createdAt": "init",
                            "updatedAt": "init",
                            "__v": "init"
                        },
                        "states": {
                            "ignore": {},
                            "default": {},
                            "init": {
                                "_id": true,
                                "like": true,
                                "reply": true,
                                "content": true,
                                "user_id": true,
                                "user_name": true,
                                "parent_comment_id": true,
                                "_report": true,
                                "createdAt": true,
                                "updatedAt": true,
                                "__v": true
                            },
                            "modify": {},
                            "require": {}
                        },
                        "stateNames": [
                            "require",
                            "modify",
                            "init",
                            "default",
                            "ignore"
                        ]
                    },
                    "pathsToScopes": {},
                    "cachedRequired": {},
                    "session": null,
                    "$setCalled": {},
                    "emitter": {
                        "_events": {},
                        "_eventsCount": 0,
                        "_maxListeners": 0
                    },
                    "$options": {
                        "skipId": true,
                        "isNew": false,
                        "willInit": true
                    }
                },
                "isNew": false,
                "_doc": {
                    "like": [
                        {
                            "_id": "5d9cb491b6678675db48872b",
                            "value": 1,
                            "_comment": "5d9cb485b6678675db48872a",
                            "user": "830052d6-e85d-450e-a1bf-b4157d122d9a",
                            "createdAt": "2019-10-08T16:08:49.141Z",
                            "updatedAt": "2019-10-08T16:08:49.141Z",
                            "__v": 0
                        }
                    ],
                    "reply": [],
                    "_id": "5d9cb485b6678675db48872a",
                    "content": "2",
                    "user_id": "830052d6-e85d-450e-a1bf-b4157d122d9a",
                    "user_name": "ronmexico",
                    "parent_comment_id": null,
                    "_report": "5d7e5dfcbf409e0f543a8cd7",
                    "createdAt": "2019-10-08T16:08:37.826Z",
                    "updatedAt": "2019-10-08T16:08:49.143Z",
                    "__v": 0
                },
                "$locals": {},
                "$init": true,
                "likeTotalForComment": 1
            }
        ]
```

These are the only attributes that should be part of the output: content, user_id, user_name, _report, parent_comment_id, like, likeTotalForComment, and reply; instead there is a lot of unexpected information.

Comment: What you're showing as output is clearly **not** the output created by `reportsMinusComments.map(/*...*/)`, because your code is clearly adding a `comment` property which is no where in the output you've quoted.

Comment: Separately, `return c['likeTotalForComment'] = { ...c, likeTotalForComment: newValue}` within your inner `map` is highly suspect. What it does is: 1. Create a new object with all of the own, enumerable property values from `c` and also a `likeTotalForComment` property initialized from `newValue`, then 2. **Assigns** that new object to a `likeTotalForComment` property on the **original** `c` object, and then 3. Returns the object created in #1 from the `map` iterator. It seems really unlikely you want to modify the original object like that.

Answer (score 0):

As [I commented](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58290937/use-of-spread-to-add-new-attribute-ads-unexpected-output#comment102946306_58290937), the output you've shown can't be the result of that `map` as it doesn't have the `comment` property you're adding.

But fundamentally, if you're doing this:

```
return {
    ...a,
    foo: "value"
};
```

...the object you create will have all of the own, enumerable properties from `a` and also a `foo` property. It will not have any others (except the usual ones it inherits from `Object.prototype`, `toString` and such).

So if you're seeing properties in your result that you don't expect, they're on `a`. ('a is the equivalent of `v` and `c` in your question's code.)

Comment: thanks for the response. `a` comes from a mongoose populate, so it seems like that is the answer.